# bus assassination mission GTA V

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I bought the vapid stock before the bus assassination mission. After completing the mission, the stock instead of growing is decreasing rapidly. Can anything be done?

Comment: Not much you can do, because you obviously killed a guy who was associated with the stock.

Answer (score 3):

This is intended behavior.

You kill the CEO of a company, the company goes crazy and the stock starts going down over time until they get back on their feet and the stock prices start going up again.

This is actually said by Lester when you start the mission:

> Lester: Penny's one of those tight-fisted billionaires, rides the same bus to and from work every day.
>
> Lester: I was thinking you could take over the route and...
>
> Franklin: drop the asshole off where he needs to go. I got it.
>
> Lester: Good. One thing, if I was you, **I wouldn't buy any Vapid stock until the acquisition falls through.**

Comment: To be completely clear for people with no knowledge of market manipulation: the assignation mission is designed to drop Vapid stock so you can buy it for cheap, wait for it to recover in a few days, and sell it when it reaches it's normal price